# Cloudflare 512 after migrate to nginx from apache2

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cloudflare

Currently I try to migrate my wordpress site, from apache2 to nginx, here's my site available setup

[image]

my wordpress is located at `/var/www`

but cloudflare always says its error 512, here's my website looks like, 
and I dont know how to debug, because when I look at nginx error log its only say

`2018/05/10 15:36:10 [notice] 3326#3326: signal process started`

[image]

Comment: Website is opening fine on my end, was it fixed?

Comment: no, I change it again using apache2